# Mean and standard deviation of all the elements in two independent lists of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, mean

I have two lists each of two data frames. For example, lst1 = [df11, df12] and lst2 = [df21, df22]. I want to compute the mean and standard deviation of corresponding elements of two lists lst1 and lst2. That is `lst3 = [mean(df11, df21), mean(df12, df22)]` and `lst4 = [std(df11, df21), std(df12, df22)]`.

The corresponding data frames are given below,

```
df11 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[99,85,93], [89,97,94], [80,95,89]]), index=["A", "B", "C"], columns = ["Sensetivity", "specificity", "Accuracy"])  
df21 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[85,99,50], [97,89,75], [95,80,60]]), index=["A", "B", "C"], columns = ["Sensetivity", "specificity", "Accuracy"])
df12 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[99,85,93], [89,97,94], [80,95,89]]), index=["A", "B", "C"], columns = ["Sensetivity", "specificity", "Accuracy"])  
df22 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[85,99,50], [97,89,75], [95,80,60]]), index=["A", "B", "C"], columns = ["Sensetivity", "specificity", "Accuracy"])
```

Also, `lst1 = [df11, df12]` and `lst2 = [df21, df22]`.

Is there a way to do this in a simplistic way in python?

EDIT: Assuming `m1 = mean(df11, df21)` and `m2 = mean(df12, df22)`, then

m1 = [image] and m2 = [image]

Also, if `s1 = std(df11, df21)` and `s2 = std(df12, df22)`, then

s1 = [image] and s2 = [image]

Comment: It is not clear what you want. What does `mean(df11, df21)` mean please? same for `std(df11, df21)`. Ideally please provide sample output of what you want

Comment: `mean(df11, df21)` indicates the average of corresponding elements in the two dataframes `df11` and `df21`. Similarly, `std(df11, df21)` indicates the standard deviation of corresponding elements in the two dataframes `df11` and `df21`. The result output matrices are shown in the figure above.

Comment: ok makes sense now, check out my alternative to your own solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the answer for this question.

As per the given information,

Number of lists, `NumberOfLists = 2`
Number of Dataframes per list, `NumberOfDfPerList = 2`

```
for i in range(NumberOfDfPerList):       
    listofDf        = [listOfDf[k][i] for k in range(NumberOfLists)]
    stats           = pd.concat(listofDf).groupby(level=0).agg(['mean','std']).swaplevel(0,1,axis=1).round(2).astype(str)           
    result          = stats['mean'] + '±' + stats['std']
    result_arr.append(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I note you got the answer yourself which is great

Here is a possible alternative

The idea is to use internal numpy representation and use numpy concatenation/mean calcs

For the mean:

```
import numpy as np
[pd.DataFrame(np.array([p1.values, p2.values]).mean(axis=0), columns = df11.columns, index = df11.index) for (p1,p2) in zip(lst1,lst2)]
```

produces a list of two dfs:

```
[   Sensetivity  specificity  Accuracy
 A         92.0         92.0      71.5
 B         93.0         93.0      84.5
 C         87.5         87.5      74.5,
    Sensetivity  specificity  Accuracy
 A         92.0         92.0      71.5
 B         93.0         93.0      84.5
 C         87.5         87.5      74.5]
```

similar for std, replace `mean` in the command above with `std`. Works for any length of arrays